# How can you set a new code template to be used to generate a new C++ class without modifying the default code template in eclipse?

Tags: templates, eclipse-cdt, code-templates

*(I have been looking everywhere for an answer but I can't find it anywhere in the Eclipse documentation and neither anywhere on stack overflow, hence this question)*

When using `New...` to create a new code template instead of overwriting the default code template for `Files`, there is no option to set this code template as default to use when generating a new file. I want to use `#pragma use` instead of an include guard and created this new header template:

[image: New Code Template]

I simply can't find a way to make eclipse use this specific template to generate a C++ Header File, instead of the default one.

How do I fix this without modifying the default one?

**EDIT:**
More exactly, I don't know how to select a custom code template when creating a new class. There is no way to select your .cpp and .h templates in the New Class Wizard. But when creating separate .cpp and .h files, using the separate New File Wizard, there is a `template` dropdown menu. Is this just an oversight in Eclipse and is there no actual way to use custom code templates when using the New Class Wizard?

Template Selection Available:
[image: Separate .h Wizard]

Template Selection Unavailable:
[image: New Class Wizard]

Comment: My guess is this is an oversight. Please feel free to file an issue at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT.

Comment: If someone else can report this bug, due to "spam" I can't report any bugs, which seems an awful way to design a bug reporting site :/

Comment: You can report bugs. You just need to email webmaster@eclipse.org to approve the account creation.